# ngFor indexing in ionic/angular is missing newlines

Tags: html, angular7, ionic4

I have the following Ionic 4/angular 7 html code. The data source is a 3-dimential javascript object. The values display OK, but I am unable to have all items (v1, v2 and v3) to always display on a new line.
I am not an expert on this so perhaps I am missing something obvious. How could this be done the simplest way?

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let v1 of this.values1">
      {{v1.name1}}
        <ion-item *ngFor="let v2 of v1.values2">
          {{v2.name2}}
            <ion-item *ngFor="let v3 of v2.values3">
              {{v3.name3}}
            </ion-item>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you add an example of what result you want? Some screenshot or picture.

Comment: Each item in the ngFor loops (refered to in my example as {{v1.name1}}
, {{v2.name2}} and {{v3.name3}}) are strings and all I want is to have them all displayed on separate lines. Somehow this is not default behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you want this result:

```
<ion-list>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let v1 of values1">
      <ion-item>
        {{ v1.name1 }}
      </ion-item>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let v2 of v1.values2">
        <ion-item>
          {{ v2.name2 }}
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let v3 of v2.values3">
          {{ v3.name3 }}
        </ion-item>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</ion-list>
```

[image: result code]

## rtpHarry update

Not sure the best etiquette to contribute to this, but I think what @Marco Chavez meant was this:

```
<ion-list>
<ng-container *ngFor="let v1 of values1">
  <ion-item>
    {{ v1.name1 }}
  </ion-item>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let v2 of v1.values2">
    <ion-item>
      {{ v2.name2 }}
    </ion-item>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let v3 of v2.values3">
      <ion-item>
        {{ v3.name3 }}
      </ion-item>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: The 3 ngFor loops are nested. This is how they should display:
A text value from 1st loop on the first line <{{ v1.name1 }}>
A text value from 2nd loop on the next line <{{ v2.name2 }}>
All text values from the 3rd loop on separte lines <{{ v3.name3 }}>

This repeats itself until all loops are done. The number of times the loops run is not fixed.
When I run your example, values from 1st and 2nd loop is OK, but all values from loop3 is still on the same line.

Comment: can you edit your post, add an example of your 3-dimensional javascript object, also with a drawing or something give a example of visual result that you expect please.

Comment: Yeah there is a small issue in the example posted.

Comment: The last example with <ng-container> on all levels solved the problem. Thanks for the help.